# Is it redundant to create a new String for a substring of another string?

Tags: java, android, string

I know that the title is not clear! But keep reading and if you can make a better title, then edit it :)

I have the following lines of code:

```
    List<Headline> headlines = new ArrayList<>();

    String openingTag = "<NEWS>";
    String closingTag = "</NEWS>";

    while(xml.contains(openingTag) && xml.contains(closingTag)) {
        String partialXml;

        partialXml = new String(xml.substring(xml.indexOf(openingTag), xml.indexOf(closingTag) + closingTag.length()));

        // Remove what I have stored in another variable using substring. But
        // substring uses the same backing array as xml, so is it going to be
        // removed from my other variable?
        xml = xml.replace(partialXml, "");

        headlines.add(makeHeadline(partialXml));
    }
```

In the Android documentations of Java's [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

```
The returned string shares this string's backing array
```

So as per my understanding, if I am going to alter `xml` variable I have to store the result of `String.substring(int, int)` in a variable using `new String(xml.substring(int, int))`

Am I right in this conclusion?

If I am right, then why Android Studio complain about this and notifys me as it is a redundant?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Note that your approach is seriously flawed. You should use an XML parser instead of manual string twiddling or regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string in Java originally consisted of a backing array of characters and a `start/length` indication (or it may be `start/end`, I can't remember - suffice to say it had enough information to use the same actual character array in a backing store when doing substrings).

This allowed strings (which are immutable) to share the same data, such as with:

```
str1 = new String("Pax is great");
str2 = str1.substring(0,3);
```

In memory, that would have looked something like:

```
str1 (backing, 0, 12)
str2 (backing, 0,  3)
          +------------+
backing = |Pax is great| (shared)
          +------------+
```

So creating a *new* string from a substring operation (which is itself a new string) was indeed redundant, as per the preceding diagram (except for one case, see below).

If you *modified* one of the strings with something like `str2 = new String("xyzzy")`, or any other operation that means it can no longer use the same characters, then it would get a *new* backing value automatically.

I believe this changed in later releases of the JVM ([1.7.0_06](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u6-bugfixes-1733378.html), look for bug ID [6924259](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6924259)). This is the case I referred to earlier, the case where the original behaviour could cause troubles where you allocated a large string, took a small substring of it, then got rid of the original.

In that case, the *small* string would have kept the *large* backing array despite the fact it didn't need it all.

That was the reason for `new String(str.substring(...))` "trick" in that it created a *new* backing array (a smaller one) for the new string when using the original method.

With the changes made that removed the sharing, `substring()` now produces a new backing array regardless. Hence the `new String(str.substring(...))` trick is no longer needed.

Comment: so String partialXml = xml.substring(xml.indexOf(openingTag), xml.indexOf(closingTag) + closingTag.length()); won't produce any warning of redundant ? is it right ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller - Ideally. It *shouldn't* because `xml.substring(xml.indexOf(openingTag), xml.indexOf(closingTag) + closingTag.length());` already returns reference to a String (which is on the heap), there is no need to *wrap* it again in another String.

Comment: So, when I used `String.replace(String, String)` and assigned its result to `xml` it will also use the older backing array which might have some strings that no other variables are using at all (since `partialXml` will point to different string on each loop. The older string assigned to it is not used in either variables.)

Answer (score 5):

It is always redundant to use the constructor of String that accepts another String as an argument, since String is immutable, and therefore there is no point in creating a new String instance that is equal to the original instance.

Comment: That may be so now, it wasn't always the case. And there may be many systems still tied to a jvm where it may not be redundant, such as app servers.

Answer (score 3):

Java `String` is immutable creating a `new String` pollutes the `intern` cache, but otherwise accomplishes nothing. It **is** redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In java String is immutable which means any string operation which results string is converted into new string object.

When you write this line,

```
String openingTag = "<NEWS>";
```

at this line java compiler has string literal (at runtime string literal is converted into object) which has common string pool.

This is String pool is represented somehow like this in object memory,

```
+-----------+  
| "<NEWS>"  |<---- openingTag
+-----------+
```

Now our "NEWS" is string object. So if you write some line which says,

```
 String subStr1 = openingTag.substring(0,2); // which returns <N
 String str1 = new String("<NEWS>");
```

Where first line from above return's brand string  which it's self is a object object.
After

```
//this is a String pool,
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                +-----------+                    +------+               |
|     str1------>| "<NEWS>"  |<---- openingTag    | "<N" |<--- subStr1   |
|                +-----------+                    +------+               |                        
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

you have written something like this,
Which says that substrings gives you string which it's self is a object and then you are passing that string object again as parameter to convert into String object. That's redundant.

```
String subStr1 = new String(openingTag.substring(0,2));
```