# when to go for new string instead of string literal in java

Tags: java

I know when we use `String s = new String("abc");` JVM will create the object in heap and when we use `String s = "abc";` the object gets created in String constant pool.

IMO, using `String s = "abc";` serves our purpose. In which case we have to go for `new String("abc");`

Comment: When you don't want string to be cached OR it's a very long string

Comment: @Azodious but you're still creating the string literal in either case.

Comment: Is this an opinion or a question?  Because if it's a question, there is MORE than enough information on how and why objects (not just strings) are created the way they are.

Comment: @AndyTurner but that won't be cached in pool. that's just syntax.

Comment: @Azodious are you sure about that?

Comment: @AndyTurner well, that's what `intern` is for. so yes, i'm confident about this.

Comment: @Azodious no, intern is for if you're loading a string from some external data source and want it to be in the string pool. If you've got `new String("foo")` in your source code, you've got `"foo"` in your string pool.

Comment: @AndyTurner so `new String("foo")` will create two objects? on heap and string pool. is that correct?

Comment: @Azodious correct. Well actually, executing `new String("foo")` doesn't create two objects, it just creates one - the `"foo"` already existed. But yes, two objects with the value `"foo"` exist after that is executed for the first time.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for clearing the mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116702/discussion-between-azodious-and-andy-turner).

Comment: Got it. no need for chat. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never necessary to create a new `String` object from a string literal - in fact, it is unnecessarily inefficient.

`String` objects are immutable, so you never have to make a defensive copy of a `String` object.

Comment: I can think of a few odd corner cases where you do want different instances of the same string...

Comment: @assylias please expand :)

Comment: @AndyTurner say you send a query to a rest WS and the query params need to be stored in a map because a badly written API forces you to, and you want to send a list (server/ws?abc=1&abc=2&abc=3), you can build an IdentityHashMap and `map.put(new String("abc"), 1); map.put(new String("abc"), 2); etc.`. I insist on the "odd" bit of my initial comment. And actually I don't have another case in mind... ;-)

Comment: @AndyTurner It was also useful on older JVM when using substring to avoid keeping reference to the original string. Not the case since Java 7u6. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632533/is-it-redundant-to-create-a-new-string-for-a-substring-of-another-string

Comment: @assylias but that isn't really relevant when creating `String` objects from a **literal**.

Comment: @assylias thanks. I agree with the oddness caveat...